# how to write in next row using python?

Tags: python, file-io, csv

1234 5678 9876 542 1231; 2333 1234 5678 579

i want to write this data in a csv (myfile.csv) file from a .txt (murtuz.txt) file such that after semi colon it starts from the next row.

I have tried the code mentioned below, it helps me to write data in csv file but i am failed to change the line after semi colon.

```
import csv  
from StringIO import StringIO
import sys

data = open("murtuz.txt","r").read()  
data1 = StringIO(data)  
print data1          
reader = csv.reader(data1, delimiter=' ',)     
for row in reader:  
    print row  

out = csv.writer(open("myfile.csv","w"), delimiter=',')  
out.writerow(row)  
sys.exit()
```

need some experts' help.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a toy example? It might be easier to do this without the `csv` module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.lineterminator),

> The reader is hard-coded to recognise either '\r' or '\n' as end-of-line, and ignores lineterminator. This behavior may change in the future.

So you can't tell the reader to treat a semicolon as a line terminator.

You can do:

```
import csv  

data = open("murtuz.txt").readlines()
outfile = open("myfile.csv","w")
out = csv.writer(outfile)
for row in data:
    row = row.strip().split(';')
    if row:
        for subrow in row:
            subrow = subrow.strip().split()
            if subrow:
                out.writerow(subrow)
outfile.close()
```

This will work for any number of semicolons per line.

Comment: thank u so0 much it works :)
but i dont know why its leaving a row blank in between :S

Comment: Try the edited version. Also, if my answer helped you, please click the check mark next to it to accept it.

Comment: it doesnot make any change :(

Comment: I can't replicate the problem. When I use your example data I don't get any blank lines, even if I add newlines etc. to the end, or blank lines in between. Please accept my answer, or edit your question with a larger part of your input file, inside `<pre>` and `</pre>`

Comment: ok thanks for your support, i have already accepted your answer.

Answer (score 3):

`csv.reader` can accept any iterable as input. In particular, you can feed it lines yielded from a generator. You can use that generator to massage your input data -- for example, to split on semicolons:

```
input csv
input textwrap
input io

def splitter(iterable):
    for line in iterable:
        for part in line.split(';'):
            yield part.strip()

f=open("murtuz.txt","r")
# with open("murtuz.txt","r") as f:     # for Python 2.6 or better
    csvobj=csv.reader(splitter(f),delimiter=' ')
    for row in csvobj:
        print(row)
f.close()
```

yields

```
['1234', '5678', '9876', '542', '1231']
['2333', '1234', '5678', '579']
['1234', '5678', '9876', '542', '1231']
['2333', '1234', '5678', '579']
```

Once you've got the reader under control, writing it out again is easy.

Comment: i cant use 'with' in python 2.5

Comment: @mama: In that case, use `f=open(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

I would parse the line.

```
newrow = str(row)
if ';' in newrow:
  fragments = newrow.split(';')
for each_fragment in fragments:
  out.writerow(each_fragment)
```

Would this work?

Comment: couldn't you do: newrow = str(row)

Comment: No? That's like doing `str(['a', 'b', 'c;', 'd', 'e'])` then splitting at the semicolon. You won't have a list any more, you'll have `"['a', 'b', 'c"` and `"', 'd', 'e']"`. How would `csvwriter` know how to parse that?

Comment: what do u mean by line.split?

Comment: newrow.split(';'), will split your rows up for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
full_file_txt = open("murtz.txt").read() #this is ugly and brute force
rows = full_file_txt.split(";") #split txt file into rows delim by ;
for row in rows:  
    print ",".join(row.split()) #split each row on space, and output as csv
```

Comment: use @untubu answer - much neater and avoids the brute force read of txt file with generators.